# Does fundamental theorem of algebra hold in multi-variable polynomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, rational-functions

Given algebraically closed field $\mathbb{F}$ and rational function in 2 variables $f(x,y)\in \mathbb{F}(x,y)$, does it factor out in linear terms $(ax+by), a,b\in \mathbb{F}$, or in other terms, is subalgebra generated by $S=\{(ax+by)^{\pm1}; a,b\in\mathbb{F}\}$ the whole space?

$$(S)= \mathbb{F}(x,y)$$

Does this at least hold in $\mathbb{C}$? Is there some general theorem which proves this for arbitrary amount of variables? If so, please refer me to the book as I would like to see the proof

Comment: The answer to your title question is given in  [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2422805/factoring-bivariate-polynomial-px-y). See also [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27657/factorizing-polynomials-of-several-variables-in-a-different-perespective?_gl=1*1vc1bxl*_ga*MTg0NzUwODI0Ni4xNjcyNjY4MTI2*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY5MjQzNTQ2NS4xMDM0LjEuMTY5MjQzNzMyNS4wLjAuMA..).

Comment: This is much too strong; any rational function of this form must be homogeneous so e.g. $x + y^2$ is already a counterexample.

Comment: How is $x+y^2$ counterexample? Both $x$ and $y^2$ are in set $S$.